# rowCount for items over 45 days old

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table and use this to show me how many days the widgets have been in stock, this is the code I am using for this

```
$getWidgets = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM widgettracker WHERE id=id");
$getWidgets->execute();
$widgets = $getWidgets->fetchAll();
    foreach ($widgets as $widget) {
$startDate = new DateTime();
$endDate = new DateTime($widget['dadded']); 
$diff = date_diff($endDate,$startDate); 
$days = (int) $diff->format('%a');
```

I have info boxes at the top of the screen giving me different widget info, what I wanted is one of these info boxes to give me a total of how many widgets have been in stock for 45 days +

I am using this code for other sections of the site but I hate working with days/dates and simply cannot get my head round where and how I put the count in for the ones over 45 days

```
$widget45days = $db->query("SELECT id FROM widgettracker WHERE widgetstatus='Widgets for Sale'");
$widget45dayscounted = $widget45days->rowCount();
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ...

Comment: You're already iterating through your widgets to get more information so you can simply increment every time `$days` is superior to 45. But if you want the SQL condition, this should work: `where dadded < date_sub(now(), 45 day)` (substract 45 days from now and if the widget was added before that, then it's older than 45 days)

Comment: Hi I am using MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM widgettracker 
WHERE dadded < NOW() - INTERVAL 45 DAY;
```

Comment: SHould be inferior. If superior, then it's younger than 45 days

Comment: Just fixed that typo :)

Comment: Thank you every day is a school day, Love this site, took about 15 minutes for something that would of took me 15 weeks

Comment: @Isitabird: You may want `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `NOW()`.